# SQL Server 2008 R2 Mgmt Studio - Different Users Displayed in Security based on who is logs in

Tags: sql, security, odbc, ssms

So I have a long story..

Somehow and for some reason three separate SQL Server Mgmt Studio versions are installed on a server I am working on, 2005, 2008R2 and 2012.

I sorted out that the one they should be using is 2008R2, however one user is having an issue connecting the the database on said server. The user had full permission to the database, yet when I go to set up her ODBC connection the database is not provided. Only the `master`, `tempdb` and a third are displayed.

When I gave the user permission I did so via rdp (windows authentication) via another user that was already successfully permissioned to that server, database and had ODBC setup. I eventually got the user that I am trying to setup, the one giving me issues, to connect to the same server via rdp and I see that almost all of the login credentials are gone and she doesn't have permission to anything. When I try to navigate to the database and look at settings she is denied the plus button option to the left of the db name.

This is the exact same server, I am only working in 2008R2 so that is the same also.

I am sure there is a logical and simple reason to this but I am not sure what it is, I am guessing that it is related to the multiple versions of SSMS.

Any ideas on how both users logging in to the same server, same instance could have different credentials setup in Security? How I could grant permission under one user for another, it successfully saves but it does not actually grant permission when I login as the other user?

I am hoping to get SA privileges and re-permission her again while she is logged into the server, but I would like to know what went wrong here so I can recognize this issue if I come across it again.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by using named pipes to login, not really fixed but worked around. A actual fix would have probably need a reinstall. I think single-user mode may also have helped work around permission issues to modify a user account.